# hugo, how to set date language

Tags: date, hugo

With Hugo, I'm creating a blog in french.
Currently all my date are displayed in english (february) but I want them to be displayed in french (février).
How to set the language ?

My `config.toml` looks like this:

```
baseURL = 'http://example.org/'
languageCode = 'fr-FR'
defaultContentLanguage = "fr"
defaultContentLang = "fr"
title = 'TITLE'
theme = "THEME"
```

I try to set `languageCode`, `defaultContentLanguage` and `defaultContentLang` to `fr` but with no success.

I don't need multi language support, I just only need french.

Comment: How are you printing the date? You probably need to use the hugo time formatter, not the default Go .Date.Format method. `{{ time.Format "desired-format" "your-date" }}`. Also "dateFormat" is an alias of time.Format. https://gohugo.io/functions/dateformat/ . Alias documented here: https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/docs/content/en/functions/dateformat.md

Comment: @BrianWagner thanks, that's working. It translate the date in my language. Could you add this as an official answer so I can approve it for the next people getting stuck ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use localization, you need to use the Hugo function `time.Format` (which has an alias `dateFormat`). It takes two parameters:

- desired format
- time.Time object, or timestamp

Example:

`{{ time.Format "Jan. 2, 2006" .Date }}`

or

`{{ dateFormat "Jan. 2, 2006" .Date }}`

Docs: https://gohugo.io/functions/dateformat/

The `.Format` method (e.g. `{{.Date.Format "Jan. 2, 2006}}`) will not apply the desired localization.